# rendering issue in d3 radial bar chart with labels

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

My customized d3 radial chart is not rendering arc for least value.
**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/3xuLh13q/4/)**

```
var width = 360,
height = 300,
barHeight = height / 2 - 40;

var formatNumber = d3.format("s");

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#F15D5D","#FAD64B"]);

var svg = d3.select('#chart').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('class','radial')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");

var data = [{
        "name": "ABC",
        "value":4
    },
    {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "value":5
    },{
        "name": "DEF",
        "value":2
    },
    {
        "name": "GHI",
        "value":3
    },{
        "name": "JKL",
        "value":1
    }];

data.sort(function(a,b) { return b.value - a.value; });

var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
var barScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(extent)
    .range([0, barHeight]);

var keys = data.map(function(d,i) { return d.name; });
var numBars = keys.length;


// X scale
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(extent)
    .range([0, -barHeight]);

// X axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x).orient("left")
    .ticks(3)
    .tickFormat(formatNumber);

// Inner circles
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(x.ticks(5))
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {return barScale(d);})
    .style("fill", "none")
    //.style("stroke", "black")
    //.style("stroke-dasharray", "2,2")
    .style("stroke-width",".5px");

// Create arcs
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d,i) { 
    var a = (i * 2 * Math.PI) / numBars;
    var b = ((i + 1) * 2 * Math.PI) / numBars;
    var d = (b-a) / 4;
    var x = a+d;
    var y = b-d;

    return x;//(i * 2 * Math.PI) / numBars; 
})
.endAngle(function(d,i) { 
    var a = (i * 2 * Math.PI) / numBars;
    var b = ((i + 1) * 2 * Math.PI) / numBars;
    var d = (b-a) / 4;
    var x = a+d;
    var y = b-d;
    return y;//((i + 1) * 2 * Math.PI) / numBars; 
})
.innerRadius(0);

// Render colored arcs
var segments = svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = 0; })
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.name); })
    .attr("d", arc);


   segments.transition().ease("elastic").duration(1000).delay(function(d,i) {return (25-i)*50;})
    .attrTween("d", function(d,index) {
        var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, barScale(+d.value));
        return function(t) { d.outerRadius = i(t); return arc(d,index); };
    });

 // Outer circle
    svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", barHeight)
    .classed("outer", true)
    .style("fill", "none")
    //.style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width",".5px");

// Apply x axis
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis);

// Labels
var labelRadius = barHeight * 1.025;

var labels = svg.append("g")
    .classed("labels", true);

labels.append("def")
    .append("path")
    .attr("id", "label-path")
    .attr("d", "m0 " + -labelRadius + " a" + labelRadius + " " + labelRadius + " 0 1,1 -0.01 0");

labels.selectAll("text")
    .data(keys)
    .enter().append("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-weight","bold")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {return "#555";})
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#label-path")
    .attr("startOffset", function(d, i) {return i * 100 / numBars + 50 / numBars + '%';})
    .text(function(d) {return d.toUpperCase(); });
```

[image]

Here the item `JKL` with value `1` is not rendered and the outerRadius is calculated as `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
var extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
```

This line sets the domain of `barScale` and `x`. However, if you do this using `d3.extent`, you're actually saying that the domain goes from the minimum value to the maximum value...

```
[1, 5];
```

... meaning that the value `1` will be mapped to the minimum value of the range.

Instead of that, set the minimum value in the domain to zero:

```
var extent = [0, d3.max(data, d=>d.value)];
```

Which will have this result:

```
[0, 5];
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a9w7c2dw/

Comment: PS: regarding your second question (*"Also how can I move the labels to the top of each segment instead of keeping with outer ring?"*), please post another question. It's always a good practice at S.O. keeping only 1 problem per question.

Comment: Sure, I will post another question.

Comment: Thanks @devo! Sorry for that, but it's common in D3-tagged questions people asking about several different problems in their charts. I always tell them to separate the problems in different, individual posts... after all, asking here at S.O. is free!

Comment: No problem, here is my second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777234/label-placement-in-d3-radial-bar-chart

Comment: Also one more logic related doubt here. Let's one of the chart value is `300` then other items will be hidden as the values are very small. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: No, I don't... That's in fact a very well known problem in dataviz, specially in pie/donut charts: what to do to represent small values? Or, better explaining, how to represent values that differ in several orders of magnitude? In extreme cases, you'll have to give up of the pie/donut chart completely, and choose another visual representation for your chart.